# Lock page text selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there an easier way besides saving and re-selecting text on an HTML page to "lock" the selection for a duration or cancel mouse events that would deselect it.

I'm working on a page where the user can select an area of text and then choose options to manipulate it.  The problem is while clicking buttons and choosing options the text can become deselected from the mouse clicks. I would like it stay selected until they choose all their options.

I've tried using unselectable,MozUserSelect,etc however that removes the current selection.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class to the selection in order to present it as selected and disable the area based on the lock criteria you mentioned e.g. a duration. I think it's a lighter approach and more flexible.